# Line with "replace" not working if i write it to function

Tags: javascript, function, replace, after-effects

please help me, whi replace not work. Thanks.
If i write line with replace out from function it is work, but inside function not work... i dont know why, because alerts work well.... It is a script for replace footage by our choice from dropdown menu.

```
//show window
var mainWindow = new Window("palette", "", undefined);
mainWindow.orientation = "column";

var iconName = ["Bourky_s_destem.mov", "Bourky.mov", "Dest_se_snehem.mov", "Jasno.mov", "Mlhy.mov", "Mrholeni.mov", "Mrznouci_dest.mov", "Oblacno.mov", "Prehanky_dest_se_snehem.mov", "Prehanky.mov", "Skorojasno.mov", "Snehove_prehanky.mov", "Snezeni.mov", "Trvali_dest.mov", "Zatazeno.mov"];

var groupOne = mainWindow.add("group", undefined, "groupOne");

//show dropdown menu

var PH_lisabon = groupOne.add("dropdownlist", undefined, iconName);
PH_lisabon.size = [200, 25];
PH_lisabon.selection = 0;


var PH_berlin = groupOne.add("dropdownlist", undefined, iconName);
PH_berlin.size = [200, 25];
PH_berlin.selection = 0;


var PH_nice = groupOne.add("dropdownlist", undefined, iconName);
PH_nice.size = [200, 25];
PH_nice.selection = 0;

var groupTwo = mainWindow.add("group", undefined, "groupOne");
var applyButton = groupTwo.add("button", undefined, "Apply");

mainWindow.center();
mainWindow.show(); 


// this is work - app.project.item(1).replace(new File(['./ikony/' + PH_berlin.selection.text]));


//click on apply button
applyButton.onClick = function() {
    findAndReplaceIcons(PH_berlin.selection.text, "PH_berlin.mov");
    
}

// replace footage
function findAndReplaceIcons(iconOnLocation, placeHolderName) {

for (var i = 1; i <= app.project.numItems; i ++) {
    if ((app.project.item(i) instanceof FootageItem) && (app.project.item(i).name === placeHolderName)) {
    
alert(iconOnLocation);
alert(placeHolderName);
alert(app.project.item(i).name);
        app.project.item(i).replace(new File(['./ikony/' + iconOnLocation]));
        
        break;
      
      
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: That `replace` method does nothing in your code, not in the function nor outside of it. The said method returns a new string, it doesn't replace in-place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is just a matter of removing the square brackets from your file path.

```
app.project.item(i).replace(new File(['./ikony/' + iconOnLocation]));
```

Should be:

```
app.project.item(i).replace(new File('./ikony/' + iconOnLocation));
```

Though I also think that it is unlikely that your attempt to use `./` for a relative reference is going to give you what you want. You may need to use something like:

```
var path = app.project.file.path + '/ikony/' + iconOnLocation;
app.project.item(i).replace(new File(path));
```

Comment: One last thing that I thought you might like to know is that you can use `$.writeln()` as sort of a `console.log()` analog. I find this a lot nicer than dealing with progressive calls to `alert()`.